# Grouping data for d3 pie chart

Tags: d3.js

A d3 newbie here. I'm trying to group all elements from a csv file to appear as a single segemnt on a pie chart.

Here is the csv file. (a simplified version of a much larger file where I'm grouping 20-30 entries):

```
colors,count
red,34
blue,33
green,21
yellow,41
red,16
red, 21
orange,51
```

This is what I'm getting now:
http://bricbracs.com/test/

I want the red colors elements and corresponding count grouped so that it appears like this:
http://bricbracs.com/test1/

There is probably a simple solution. Here is the d3 script. Nothing fancy, just you're standard pie chart.

```
<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.count; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.colors); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.colors; });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this one.  If you want a straight `d3` solution, how about a [d3.nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest):

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.colors;
    })
    .rollup(function(d) {
      return d3.sum(d, function(g) {
        return g.count;
      });
    }).entries(data);

...
```

Full example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/h7aemTNIbodntSFSxjow?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

When I have to do data transformation tasks for d3 I prefer to do it on the back end because you can mock out the data and run tests against your transformation engine. Then you're just sending the data out to d3. To wit:

(C# MVC Web Api example)

```
public class RestaurantViewModel
{
    public List<RestaurantDataSeries> RestaurantData { get; set; }
}
public class RestaurantDataSeries
{
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public List<ScoreDataPoint> DataSeries { get; set; }
}

public class ScoreDataPoint
{
    public string Score { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public RestaurantViewModel GetRestaurantSeries()
{
    var csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration();
    csvConfiguration.RegisterClassMap<RestaurantDataMap>();
    const string fileName = "Restaurant_Inspection_Scores_Chart.csv";
    using (var streamReader = _fileSource.GetFile(fileName))
    {
        var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, csvConfiguration);
        var restaurantDataPoints = csvReader.GetRecords<RestaurantData>().ToList();
        var zipcodes =
            restaurantDataPoints.DistinctBy(point => point.Zipcode).Select(point => point.Zipcode).ToList(); //Distinct zips

        var restaurantDataSeries = new List<RestaurantDataSeries>();
        var scoreList = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
        foreach (var zipcode in zipcodes)
        {
            var currentRestaurantDataSeries = new RestaurantDataSeries
            {
                Zipcode = zipcode,
                DataSeries = new List<ScoreDataPoint>()
            };

            foreach (var score in scoreList)
            {

                currentRestaurantDataSeries.DataSeries.Add(new ScoreDataPoint
                {
                    Score = score,
                    Count =
                        restaurantDataPoints.Count(
                            point => point.Zipcode == zipcode && ScoreConverter.GetScore(point.Score) == score)
                });
            }
            restaurantDataSeries.Add(currentRestaurantDataSeries);
        }

        return new RestaurantViewModel {RestaurantData = restaurantDataSeries};
    }
}
```

Then I consume the formatted list in D3 all simple-like without having to do my data transformation in javascript. But then again, I find working with data **much** simpler in statically typed languages where I can do verification on the names and transformations at compile time instead of runtime.